# Thread cleanup during various cases

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new thread programming.

I was told cleanup handlers have to be maintained to clean the dynamically allocated thread specific data or thread specific stack data,when the threads are cancelled or exited without the complete execution of particular code.

What is case when the threads are returned normally after executing particular piece of code.How will local stack data or dynamically allocated data get cleaned up in C++?Do we maintain cleanup handlers for this purpose also?

I am using posix threads.

Lets say I have a function which will be called by different threads and in the function I have dynamically allocated data.

In the case of thread cancellation or thread exit,I can register a function where deallocation can be done using pthread_cleanup_push and pthread_cleanup_pop calls.

What is case if the thread is executed properly with out any exit or cancellation in between.

Thanks.

Comment: What threading library are you using? The C++11 std::thread one, Boost.Thread, POSIX threads, or some other platform-specific library? And how are you allocating your thread-specific data?

Comment: Edited the question with required info.thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was told cleanup handlers have to be maintained to clean the dynamically allocated thread specific data or thread specific stack data,when the threads are cancelled or exited without the complete execution of particular code.

If you use `pthread_setspecific` to create thread-specific data then you can provide a "destructor" function (not the same as a C++ destructor) when calling `pthread_key_create` and the destructor function will be run when the thread exits.

I don't know what you mean by "thread specific stack data". You don't need to do anything to cleanup stack data.

> What is case when the threads are returned normally after executing particular piece of code.How will local stack data or dynamically allocated data get cleaned up in C++?Do we maintain cleanup handlers for this purpose also?

When a thread exits (either normally or abnormally) destructors for thread-specific data will be run. In C++11 destructors for `thread_local` variables will be run.

If you exit a function then the usual rules of C++ apply, destructors are run for stack obejcts. Dynamically allocated resources are not freed automatically, so you should use RAII. Using threads doesn't change anything in that respect, a C++ function is still a C++ function.

> In the case of thread cancellation or thread exit,I can register a function where deallocation can be done using pthread_cleanup_push and pthread_cleanup_pop calls.

If you're using GCC and GNU libc then thread cancellation is implemented by throwing a special exception type, which will cause destructors to run. So if you write good, clean C++ using RAII then everything just works and you don't need to use `pthread_cleanup_push`. This is not portable however.

> What is case if the thread is executed properly with out any exit or cancellation in between.

Then your function returns normally and destructors run normally, of course. Using threads doesn't suddenly change the rules of C++.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan.Really helpful.Which is a better implementation  during thread cancellation-throwing exception or proper cleanup?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Implementation of what, cancellation? You seem to be comparing how GNU implements cancellation with how your code implements cleanup ... they're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

First of all are you using C++11?

If you are using it, look at the documentation of [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and the examples there. If you are using C++ new thread facilities, then the handlers are just like any other C++ object. If you destroy them properly as objects, the clean up is correctly done.

If you cannot use C++11 or want to use some other library, then you should specify and probably your best practice will be to encapsulate them into a "object manager" and manage memory from there.

Edit: Ok, talking about pthreads. But if you plan to use pthread_cleanup and things like that, then you can drop the C++. The idea (one of them) behind C++ is encapsulation and clean memory management. If you plan to manually use the hooks and callbacks used in C, then do so. But I would do not advise it.

Answer (score 2):

> Lets say I have a function which will be called by different threads
>   and in the function I have dynamically allocated data.

OK. Since you're writing C++, all this dynamically-allocated data will be owned by a smart pointer, right?

> In the case of thread cancellation or thread exit,I can register a
>   function where deallocation can be done using pthread_cleanup_push and
>   pthread_cleanup_pop calls.

You *can* do this, but probably never should. The rules for correct use of `pthread_cancel` are:

1. don't
2. really don't do this
3. under no circumstances do this in idiomatic C++, because it doesn't interact with stack unwinding (ie, none of your smart pointers or local-scope objects will be destroyed)
4. there are some situations where it may be ok, but it's very hard to do correctly
5. if you're asking this question, you're probably not in one of those situations
6. I'm not kidding, don't use `pthread_cancel`

> What is case if the thread is executed properly with out any exit or cancellation in between.

If you *have* written `pthread_cleanup_push` handlers already, just call `pthread_cleanup_pop` at the appropriate place, and pass a nonzero `execute` argument. This is exactly equivalent to the way a C++ object executes its destructor on going out of scope, whether that's because the block ended normally or an exception was thrown.

---

NB. If you're using GCC (a test shows Jonathan Wakely is correct, which honestly surprised me), the above warnings are overblown. If you are or might use a different compiler or pthread implementation, you should really stay away and implement your own mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The pthreads library (not sure if this is what you are using) has pretty easy methods for cleanup handlers.  There are ways you can register cleanup handlers if you want. Take a look at [this man page for pthread_cleanup_push](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html).

However, as long as you don't have any memory leaks or anything just returning threads normally should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Call me conservative, but I never use official thread stopping methods (e.g. `pthread_cancel()`). Usually there are several points in the program, which is extremly hard to clean up, if the thread stops at one of these points.

Just a simple example: I usually set file descriptors to -1 after closing them.

```
  close(fd);
  fd = -1;
```

The cleanup code, which closes `fd` should be:

```
 if (fd != -1) close(fd);
```

But if the tread stops right after the `close(fd)`, which is before the `fd = -1`, the cleanup code fails (okay, it's not a big mistake to perform `close(-1)`, but you can easy imagine worse cases).

So, I'm using *"stop request"* flag for the thread, which is set to `false` at thread start, and set to `true` by another (controller, main) thread. The thread itself checks it periodically, and if it's `true`, performs a cleanup and exits. Because "break point" is known for the thread, cleanup is not a problem.